# PHP: display one column as array field

Tags: php, mysql

This is antivirus_detail table:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------

| Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra
|
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------

| Emp_id                      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |

| Computer_id                 | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |

| Antivirus_id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |auto_incre
                                                                          ment 
| Antivirus_name              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |

| Antivirus_key               | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |

| Antivirus_installation_date | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |

| Antivirus_expiration_date   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

This is hardware_description table:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Computer_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Emp_id           | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PC_type          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Operating_system | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Product_key      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Assign_date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Emp_id is foreign key on both these tables from a different employees table & Computer_id is foreign key in antivirus table from hardware_description table.

This is my php code:

```
<?php require_once 'includes/dbconnection.php'; ?>
<?php require_once 'includes/functions.php'; ?>

<?php
    $id="1";

    $sql ="SELECT b.*, c.* FROM hardware_description b, antivirus_detail c WHERE b.Computer_id = c.Computer_id AND c.Emp_id = '$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    //var_dump($result);

?>

    <table cellpadding="5" border="0">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Employee ID</th>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Computer ID</th>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Operating System</th>
            <th style="text-align: left;">PC Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Antivirus ID</th>

        </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Emp_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Computer_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Operating_system']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['PC_type']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Antivirus_id']; ?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>
    </table>
```

Now, this displays:

```
Employee ID Computer ID Operating System PC Type Antivirus ID 
1            2           Windows XP      Desktop    1          
1            2           Windows XP      Desktop    2
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Employee ID Computer ID Operating System PC Type   Antivirus ID
1              2          Windows XP     Desktop   1,2
```

I want all the Antivirus IDs belinging to a Computer ID to be displayed as an array. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to do it with two queries??

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I don't mind two queries. Just want the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query, you have to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate Antivirus_ids.

Change your SQL query to something like this;

```
$sql ="SELECT b.Emp_id, b.Computer_id, b.Operating_system, b.PC_type, GROUP_CONCAT(c.Antivirus_id SEPARATOR ', ') as concatenated_ids FROM hardware_description b, antivirus_detail c WHERE b.Computer_id = c.Computer_id AND c.Emp_id = '$id' GROUP BY c.Antivirus_id";
```

And on fetching data side change this `$row['Antivirus_id'];` to `$row['concatenated_ids'];`.

Comment: Although I had to make one change,  `GROUP BY c.Antivirus_id` assigned all `Antivirus_id` to one `Computer_id` I changed it to `GROUP BY c.Computer_id`